# Smooth point of a variety over $\mathbb C$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety over $\mathbb C$ of dimension $n$. For a fixed point $p$, we assume there exists a regular map $f$ from an open neighborhood of $p$ to $\mathbb C^n$.

Suppose there exists an open set $U$ of $p$ with respect to the complex topology such that $f$ is an embedding on $U$, can we prove that $p$ must be smooth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. By a theorem from Griffiths & Harris, the Jacobian of $f$ must be non-vanishing, hence $p$ must be smooth.

(see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44947/holomorphy-of-inverse-map)